# How to make a file:// link in GitHub flavoured markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

We are using a private GitHub repro to host markdown files as a wiki for a project.

I need to link to a file on file share, but I can't get GitHub to render the hyperlink.

I have tried:

```
[link](\\foo\bar.doc)
```

But this renders as a relative link.

I also tried putting raw HTML into the markdown file:

```
<a href="file://\\foo\bar.doc">link</a>
```

But GitHub's sanitiser seems to strip that out.

Is this supported, and if so what syntax should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a conversation with GitHub support, and as of today this is not supported.

There is an old issue where this was discussed:

https://github.com/github/markup/issues/426